# python and matplotlib and changing marker color

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, wxpython, matplotlib-basemap

I am plotting things using matplotlib and Basemap (within a wxpython gui).  Currently, my plot code look something like this:

```
self.map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=lon_L, llcrnrlat=lat_D, urcrnrlon=lon_R,
                               urcrnrlat=lat_U, projection='lcc', lat_0=map_lat1, lon_0=map_lon1, 
                               resolution='i', area_thresh=10000,ax=self.axes, fix_aspect=False) 

 m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=lon_L, llcrnrlat=lat_D, urcrnrlon=lon_R,
                        urcrnrlat=lat_U, projection='lcc', lat_0=map_lat1, lon_0=map_lon1, 
                        resolution='i', area_thresh=10000,ax=self.axes)

x,y=m(some_x_data,some_y_data)
plot_handle, = self.map.plot(x,y,'bo')
plot_handle.set_xdata(x)
plot_handle.set_ydata(y)

self.figure.canvas.draw()
```

This plots it just fine.  Now what I want to do is take a single point (single x and single y within my data) and color it a different color.  I still want to use the plot_handle because I am constantly updating the map/plot -- so i don't want to just reset my data.  Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a new plot_handle for the specific plot with a different marker:

```
plot_handle1, = self.map.plot([x[i]], [y[i]], 'ro')
```

You'll then have to update this every time you want to change that point's position. It's not possible to use only one plot_handle and have points showing with different markers.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `scatter` ([doc](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter)) you can set and update the color of each point.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
x,y = m(some_x,some_y)
c = iterator_of_colors
plt_handle, = self.map.scatter(x,y,c=c)
# some code
c[j] = new_color   # update you color list 
plt_handle.set_array(c) # update the colors in the graph
plt.draw()
```

It looks a little strange to use `set_array` but that is how `matplotlib` deals with scatter plots internally (it looks like they use the same class that is used for displaying images, only just color in markers instead of squares in the grid).